# Workspace Integrity error when trying to install CocoaPods

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

While trying to integrate a CocoaPod (e.g. Firebase), I get the
"Couldn't load [projectname].xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace" error no matter what I've tried and fixes I've researched.

Here's my steps:

1. Create new single-view Xcode project (e.g. Firebase.xcodeproj).
2. Create Podfile:

   ```
   target 'Firebase' do 
   platform :ios, '11.0' 

   pod 'Firebase' 
   pod 'Firebase/Core' 
   pod 'Firebase/Database' 
   pod 'Firebase/Auth' 

   end
   ```
3. Exit out of Xcode completely.
4. Navigate to the project folder in terminal.
5. Run "pod install"
6. Receive the Pod installation complete and success notices
7. Double click on the newly created "Firebase.xcworkspace"

Get the Workspace Integrity error: "Couldn't load Firebase.xcodeproj because it is already opened from another project or workspace"

Comment: did you try also the other way -> open Xcode -> open project (source project) ?

Comment: If I just open the source project I get an Apple Mach-O Linker Error and a bunch of Apple Mach-O Linker Warnings looking like "Directory not found for option -..../Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..../GoogleToolboxforMac"

Comment: hm, seems you opened the "normal" project file. you should stick to the "Firebase.xcworkspace". did you try to clean your project?

Comment: Might be a problem with the name - Firebase is the name of your project, the target, and the pod you are importing. Try naming it something else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using git for your project then commit all your changes. This removed the "integrity" warning for me.